# Why do fiber optic cables have the size they do?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

We all know that fiber optics are very small, but my question is, why are they small? Does it give them some advantage in transmission of data? If yes then how? What would happen if we make the fiber optics larger in size, or even smaller?

Comment: It is hard to see why this question got down voted. Diameter is an important characteristic. The reason isn't obvious to everyone who wants to use a fiber optic cable.

Comment: I did some amendments in my question. Hope it's easier to understand now... I am ofcourse talking about the diameter of the cable here :)

Comment: This is a good question (since the edit). Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a fiber optic as in fiber optic cables, consider this:They work on the principle of total  internal reflection to transmit electromagnetic  signals without losses. Now these have a certain critical angle(look it up),which is primarily a characteristic of the optic cable.However if you were to change the size, say diametrically, one would have to change the angle of incidence at which the light pulse would need to interact with the cable for long distances of transmission without loss. You might have noticed that such cables are really not so thick.
Hope this helps, pardon me if I went off track a bit.

Comment: so smaller size of fiber optic is better for long distance transmissions without loss? But why?

Comment: There are many factors which go into the design oa a fiber optic cable. The first question is: what dobyou want to send? If its just the distribution of lighting, or is it a communications channel? Are you sending data or high powered laser pulses? Are you preserving polarization? Taking a simple case, the cable will have a core, cladding, and an exterior protective coating. The core and cladding jointly determine optical performance. For a given optical source - usually a laser - the cable will support a single optical mode (thinner) or will be mult-modal (thicker).  For an introduction see h

Comment: http://www.data-connect.com/Fiber_Tutorial.htm

Comment: For long distance optical communications (>km) where the cores are somewhere in the 5 to 20 micron diameter range, they are real, honest to goodness dielectric waveguides. They do not use total internal reflection per se, although like everything in optics, the macroscopic can be viewed as a limiting case of the microscopic. For short distance communications, like a few hundred meters down to connecting your overpriced audio equipment, those can be thought of as using total internal reflection, although you can also treat them as extremely high order multimode waveguides.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6835/37364), but the answer isn't entirely complete. Yes total internal reflection describes larger diameter cables. But for some applications, a thin cable is better. For a thin cable, the diameter is near the wavelength of light. The wave properties of light become important. In this regime, people talk about the modes of a cable.

One way to think of modes is that diffraction affects the shape of the beam as the beam progresses down the cable. The cable must be designed so that diffraction and the cable work together to keep the beam cross section constant.

Another way of saying this is light is a propagating electromagnetic wave, and the fiber is the boundary condition of the wave. Modes are different solutions to the wave equation. They have different cross sections.

A single mode is usually desirable because multiple modes propagate differently and get out of phase. Often the lowest mode with the smoothest cross section is the most desirable.

For a more physics oriented description, here are some course notes on [Optical Waveguides](http://www.optics.rochester.edu/users/gpa/opt468a.pdf) from the U of Rochester. If you aren't interested in details of solving Maxwell's equations, you still might find useful information about how waveguides are constructed.

For a more commercial slant, you might try [RP Photonics' Encyclopedia/Buyer's Guide](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html). Here is an article on [Modes](https://www.rp-photonics.com/encyclopedia.html), and here is one on [Single-mode Fibers](https://www.rp-photonics.com/single_mode_fibers.html).